# How to write down the equations?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I am new at the website. I see that there are equations in many posts as well as in the answers. I can't write down this equation in this website. But I need to write it.

This may seems to off-topic. Can anyone help me writing the equations in a question or in the answers in the website?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and you'll be typing equations in no time.

Another way to learn is to see how other users make their expressions. If you see an interesting math expression, just right click on the expression and select "Show Math As", then select "TeX Commands". A window will pop up displaying the code that was used to type the expression.

Here's an example of an equation
$$ ax^2+bx+c=0 $$
To type this, I entered "\$\$ ax^2+bx+c=0 \$\$", without the quotes.